# Get the correct size of a JLabel with html before painting

Tags: java, html, swing

I have a problem with HTML-rendering in a JLabel. I am not quite sure what happens but when I call the setFadedVisible the first time, it seems like it calculates a size where the html is not rendered, paint it, render the html, recalculate and repaint agian. I only get a short glimpse of the wrong size before it is repainted correctly, but it is enough to be annoyed. When i put non-HTML text in the textlabel it doesn't happens (because it is a single line i guess). Can you help me with this?

```
public class LevelEndLayeredPane extends FadedLayer {
    ...

    private void showMessageAndSetVisible(String mes) {
        mes = mes.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
        mes = "<html><center>" + mes + "</center></html>";
        textLabel.setText(mes);
        setFadedVisible(true);
    }
    ...
}


public class FadedLayer extends JLayeredPane{

private JComponent fadedLayer;
private JComponent groundLayer;
private JComponent topLayer;

public FadedLayer(JComponent groundLayer) {
    setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));
    setOpaque(false);
    createFadedLayer();
    add(groundLayer, Integer.valueOf(0));
    add(fadedLayer, Integer.valueOf(1));
    fadedLayer.setVisible(false);
}

public FadedLayer(JComponent groundLayer, JComponent topLayer) {
    this(groundLayer);
    setTopLayer(topLayer);
}

public void setFadedVisible(boolean show){
    fadedLayer.setVisible(show);
}

public boolean isFadedVisible() {
    return fadedLayer.isVisible();
}
...

}
```

Comment: Are you possibly trying to modify the label outside the event dispatch thread? That's a good way to get odd effects like you describe.

Comment: Otherwise provide an example code that is executable and reproduces the behavior.